# Pandas Unicode Import Export error with to_excel() read_excel()

Tags: python, string, pandas, unicode, export-to-excel

Morning.

I have condensed a much larger situation down to the following:

I have one file with a dataframe with some values in it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'joe': [['dog'], ['cat'], ['fish'], ['rabbit']], 'ben': [['dog'], ['fish'], ['fish'], ['bear']]})

df:
      ben       joe
0   [dog]     [dog]
1  [fish]     [cat]
2  [fish]    [fish]
3  [bear]  [rabbit]
```

The type of data contained within this dataframe is as follows:

```
type(df.iloc[2,1]),df.iloc[2,1]
>>> (list, ['fish'])
```

When I save the dataframe to excel using `pd.to_excel()`:

```
writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('Input Output Test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer1,'Sheet1')
writer1.save()
```

I immediately read this back in to the same file as follows:

```
dfi = pd.read_excel(open('Input Output Test.xlsx'), sheetname='Sheet1')
```

I again test the type of the data:

```
type(dfi.iloc[2,1]),dfi.iloc[2,1]
>>> (unicode, u"['fish']")
```

The data is now in unicode format. This is problematic, as, when I compare the two dataframes as follows, all results are false, due to the non matching string formats:

```
np.where(df['joe'] == dfi['joe'],True,False)
dfi:
        ben         joe   test
0   ['dog']     ['dog']  False
1  ['fish']     ['cat']  False
2  ['fish']    ['fish']  False
3  ['bear']  ['rabbit']  False
```

What is going on during the read and write process that is causing this change, and how I change it to maintain `str` format post save?

E: Unfortunately, the nature of my problem dictates that the dataframe must be saved, and manipulated within a different file.

Edit, in response to EdChum's comment: if I instead store these strings as strings, not lists: I still get the same error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'joe': ['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'rabbit'], 'ben': ['dog', 'fish', 'fish', 'bear']})

    ben     joe
0   dog     dog
1  fish     cat
2  fish    fish
3  bear  rabbit

writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('Input Output Test Joe.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer1,'Sheet1')
writer1.save()

dfi = pd.read_excel(open('Input Output Test Joe.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Sheet1')

type(dfi.iloc[2, 1]), dfi.iloc[2, 1]
(unicode, u'fish')
```

And again, the comparison fails.

Edit: 
Evaluation of Unicode to a regular string can also be achieved via `ast.literal_eval()` as described here: 
[Convert string representation of list to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python) or as EdChum's suggestion.

Note, If you use `to_csv()` and `read_csv()` this issue is not present.

But why does `to_excel() / re_excel()` change the original code?

Comment: not sure if what you posted is correct but storing a list as the datatype when the list only contains a single string seems fundamentally wrong, can you not just store them as normal strings whereby all the comparisons will just work

Comment: Hi @EdChum Thanks for the feedback. You mentioned this to me in a previous question actually... unfortunately it's a drawback of the data and methods I have inherited - I must work in the format I have been given. In addition, for the above dataframe, if I remove the lists and just make them strings, I still get this error.

Comment: I don't suppose you could switch to Python 3...

Comment: I think you can just do `df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])` to convert the dtype from a list to just plain string then you can do `np.where(df['ben'] == df['joe'],True,False)` which will just work

Comment: does passing `encoding='ascii'` to `to_excel` work?

Comment: What you say is true, Unfortunately, the nature of my problem dictates that the dataframe must be saved, and manipulated within a different file.

Comment: @EdChum No, it does not.

Comment: can you try without the `writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter('Input Output Test.xlsx')` line so just `df.to_excel(Input Output Test.xlsx,'Sheet1', encoding='ascii')`

Comment: @EdChum Just tried - no luck.

Comment: Sorry out of suggestions, I don't have the pre-requisite libs installed in order to try to reproduce this, best of luck

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: I can reproduce the last @EdChum example, and for me the comparison works, even thought `df` is `str` and `dfi` is unicode type.

Comment: @FabioLamanna The test works as it compares columns `joe` and `ben` within the **same** dataframe `df`. In my example (which is just for brevity's sake) I am trying to compare the column `joe`  in  `df` and column `joe` in `dfi`. `dfi` suffers from the unicode error I have described.

Comment: @CharlesMorris actually I did compare them with your code `np.where(df['joe'] == dfi['joe'],True,False)` and it returns `array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`

Comment: @FabioLamanna My apologies. You are correct! The conversion does work, even across the weird Unicode format. EdChum, if you want to post that as a workaround answer, I'll accept, Thank you, as usual for your most helpful commentary. I do wonder why the original problem exists still though.

Answer (score 2):

> But why does to_excel() / re_excel() change the original code?

I don't know. I briefly looked at the source of `to_excel` `from_excel`, but couldn't find any clues.
Setting `engine='xlsxwriter'` and leaving `encoding` to default seems to do it, i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'joe': [['dog'], ['cat'], ['fish'], ['rabbit']], 'ben': [['dog'], ['fish'], ['fish'], ['bear']]})

with pd.ExcelWriter ('Input Output Test.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='xlsxwriter')

dfi = pd.read_excel('Input Output Test.xlsx')

assert eval(dfi.iloc[2,1]) == df.iloc[2,1]
# True
```